# angular nested views not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, frontend

I want to build an email client application where user would see a login panel first and then will be redirected to main view with few other views inside. Like received emails, removed, spam ect. To do that I used ui-router and nested views and my config code look like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider
.state('/',{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCTRL'
})
.state('main',{
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'views/mainView.html',
    controller: 'MailCtrl'

}),
.state('main.received', {
    url: '/received',
    templateUrl: '/views/received.html' ,
    controller: 'receivedCTRL'
     })

     })
.state('main.spam', {
    url: '/spam',
    templateUrl: '/views/spam.html',
    controller: 'spamCTRL' 

     })
.state('main.removed', {
    url: '/removed',
    templateUrl: '/views/removed.html',
    controller: 'removedCTRL' 

     })
.state('main.message', {
    url: '/message',
    templateUrl: '/views/FullMessage.html',
    controller: 'MailCtrl' 

     }) });
```

But instead of displaying all the nested views on my email panel it sends me back to login view. All the paths are correct.

Comment: can you please provide the content of `views/mainView.html`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g6j7e6yp/ <--- here it is. The ui-view section is on a very bottom of the code.

Comment: There's some typos in your states config: `main.received` and `main.message` are closing twice, and there's a comma after state `main`. Please let me know if that's also present in your code or just here.

Comment: accidentally that was my mistake when copying code here. There are no double closing brackets within my original code. My JS console does not send me any error syntax messages

Comment: And are you using `ui-sref` as suggested by Judson Terrell below? or in javascript `$state.go('state_name_here')`?

Comment: I use ui-view directive for both my index and mainView file

Comment: Please include the code that attempts to redirect to main view

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fzc3mx0h/ all the views are email lists repeated by angular

Comment: I meant the login controller

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a1dg7f6v/   <-- here is my login controller

Comment: Updated my answer to address what seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the template used in `main` state has a nameless `ui-view`. Something like:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

At least 1 ui-view is required in parent states for it's child to populate (unless you use some really advanced configuration)

**UPDATE**

When using ui-router, use `$state` instead of `$location`. `$state` is the service made to navigate between states and can be use with states' names.

In your `loginCtrl` try changing `$location.path` for `$state.go('main')` (remember to include the dependency for `$state` in the controller's parameters)

Also, when creating links in HTML, use `ui-sref="state_name"` as Judson Terrell suggested.

Usually when ui-router redirects to the default URL it's because it couldn't find a state for the URL provided. With this approach you can make sure that the URL provided to the browser is the same as the one configured for your states.

If this doesn't work, try also commenting the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` line to avoid redirection.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if `/` is a valid state name... I'd change it to something else just in case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the issue? You need this instead?

```
$stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/login'})
```

also I assume you are linking like this..

```
<a ui-sref="mystate">Go To My State</a>
```